# Rails 5.2 and webpacker 3.4.3: Assets not compiled when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

I've just upgraded my Rails app from 5.1.6 to 5.2 and took the chance to also upgrade Webpacker from 2.0 to 3.4.3.

Now, when I push the app to Heroku I get the following error (vendor.js is one the files in `/app/javascript/packs` and his called by `javascript_pack_tag 'vendor'` in my application.html.erb template):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find vendor.js in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes: 
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment 
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server. 
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates. 
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file. 
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest. 
Your manifest contains: 
{ 
} 
):
```

And Indeed, when I examine the content of `/public` I can see that the `/packs` directory supposed to contains my assets is missing.

I can see that during the build phase on Heroku, assets are precompiled:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.5.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
       warning " > coffee-loader@0.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "coffeescript@>= 1.8.x".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 36.65s.
       Webpacker is installed  
       Using /tmp/build_d6c1dd8314f746d28a2469f2a01ec4ed/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
       Compiling…
       Compiled all packs in /tmp/build_d6c1dd8314f746d28a2469f2a01ec4ed/public/packs
       Asset precompilation completed (119.53s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
```

My `/config/webpacker.yml` file is the following

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

If I change `compile: false` to `compile: true` in `production:`, compilation works but without minification and gzipping.

My `/webpack/production.js` is:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment
```

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I should add that compiling my assets locally with

`NODE_ENV=production ./bin/webpack`

works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yannis did you ever solve this?

Comment: @SimonCooper Unfortunately not. I'm still on webpacker 2.0 for the time being. I'll address this issue again soon.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637002/3468846) answer

```rb
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled=true` # ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```